# Can I save an email from Gmail to a drive

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to save an email from Gmail into a folder on my hard drive, complete with attachments?  This is another of these actions that is so easy in Microsoft Outlook and so difficult to work out in Gmail.

Comment: Why dont you sign into your gmail too on Outlook?

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea.....so you know what my next question is.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on called "[Save Emails and Attachment](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-emails-and-attachmen/nflmnfjphdbeagnilbihcodcophecebc)s" that you can use to download email messages and file attachments from Gmail to Google Drive automatically. But emails are archived as PDF files.The add-on is completely free but there’s a premium version as well that offers a few additional benefits.

All you have to do is visually create a rule, similar to how your create filters in Gmail, and then specify a folder in your Google drive. The add-on runs in the background and will automatically download the matching emails to the corresponding Drive folder

Internally,there’s a Google Script that is doing the work.It connects to your Gmail, pulls the matching threads and saves them to Drive via the various Google Apps Script APIs

```
function sendToGoogleDrive() { 

  var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var gmailLabels  = sheet.getRange("D4:D4").getValue();  
  var driveFolder  = sheet.getRange("D5:D5").getValue();  
  var archiveLabel = sheet.getRange("D6:D6").getValue();

  var moveToLabel =  GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(archiveLabel);

  if ( ! moveToLabel ) {    
    moveToLabel = GmailApp.createLabel(archiveLabel);    
  }

  var filter = "has:attachment -label:" + archiveLabel + " label:" + gmailLabels;

  var threads = GmailApp.search(filter, 0, 5);  

  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveFolder);

  if (folder.hasNext()) {
    folder = folder.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(driveFolder);
  }

  for (var x=0; x<threads.length; x++) {

    var message = threads[x].getMessages()[0];

    var desc   = message.getSubject() + " #" + message.getId();
    var att    = message.getAttachments();

    for (var z=0; z<att.length; z++) {
      try {
        file = folder.createFile(att[z]);
        file.setDescription(desc);
      }
      catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e.toString());
      }
    }

    threads[x].addLabel(moveToLabel);    
  }

}


function configure() {  
  reset();  
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendToGoogleDrive").timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();  
  Browser.msgBox("Initialized", "The program is now running.", Browser.Buttons.OK);  
}

function onOpen() {  
  var menu = [    
    { name: "Step 1: Authorize",   functionName: "configure" },
    { name: "Step 2: Run Program", functionName: "configure" },
    { name: "Uninstall (Stop)",    functionName: "reset"     }
  ];  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .addMenu("Gmail Attachments", menu);
}

function reset() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();  
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);    
  }

}
```

[Source](https://www.labnol.org/internet/send-gmail-to-google-drive/21236/) 
**Hope this answer helps!**

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that would be wonderful for someone who is technical :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the ***Save emails to Google Drive*** extension for Chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-emails-to-google-dri/glgaegbgegomicnedooifcbnmppmofkf

Comment: We posted the answer at the same time :D !!!!

Comment: Thank you but I don't find it easy when Google takes over my life because Google and I don't use the same logic.  Maybe if all else fails.